# Entity Framework 6 Adding properties to join tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, e-commerce, entity-framework-6

This is the scenario:
I have a products table and a categories table. The relationship is many-to-many: a category can have 1 or more products....and a product can be in 1 or more categories...

The Code-First mapping looks like this....

```
public class Product
{
  //...additional properties...
  public virtual ICollection<Category> AssociatedCategories {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
  //...additional properties...
  public virtual ICollection<Product> AssociatedProducts {get; set;}
}
```

Now, under the hood, entity framework will create a join table called ProductCategory with columns ProductID and CategoryID. That's great....

Here's the thing though, I need to introduce a sort order...basically just a cardinal positioning index, but this number exists only at the part in the relationship where product and category meet each other. For example, a product X might have a sort order value of "5" in Category Y, but that some product--X--could have a different sort value--say 10--in Category Z.

Naturally, I could create an entity specifically for this type of thing...but it would require a new table be made...there would be 3 columns for the Category ID, Product ID, and sort order. What I'd really like to be able to do is tap into the table that entity framework already made....it will already keep track of products IDs and category IDs in the join table....is there any way to make use of the table that already exists?

Comment: You're gonna have to create an entity in the class model, otherwise EF will never be able to read the sort order. Don't worry. In most real-world applications pure junction tables sooner or later turn out to be an academic abstraction. Also, when the junction is an entity you can manipulate the associations far more efficiently.

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan to have a sort order for different Products if you don't store it somewhere, hence you will need to add that column to the table.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold...

I'm curious about what you said...that "when the junction is an entity you can manipulate the associations far more efficiently"...

Is what you're talking about something similar to what Dismissile posted using the fluent API?

Comment: I meant that you can create/delete the association records themselves, even without ever fetching a `Product` or `Category` from the database. With many-to-many you always need the full objects to manipulate the associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a specific entity for the join table in order to do this.

```
public class Product
{
  //...additional properties...
  public virtual ICollection<ProductCategoryXref> AssociatedCategories {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
  //...additional properties...
  public virtual ICollection<ProductCategoryXref> AssociatedProducts {get; set;}
}

public class ProductCategoryXref
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    // Additional Columns...

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

If you are using the Fluent API to configure your entities it will look something like this:

```
 public class ProductCategoryXrefMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductCategoryXref>
 {
      ProductCategoryXrefMap()
      {
           HasKey(pk => new { pk.ProductId, pk.CategoryId });
           HasRequired(p => p.Product).WithMany(p => p.AssociatedCategories).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.ProductId);
           HasRequired(p => p.Category).WithMany(p => p.AssociatedProducts).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.CategoryId);
           ToTable("ProductCategoryXref");
      }
 }
```

Comment: So I managed to get something similar to your code sample up and running...it looks like by doing this, it can use the same JOIN table...but it's going to create duplicate entries....one row to store the category to product association...and one row to store the sort order to cat/product association

Comment: thanks @Dismille....I'm actually going to just test what it's like to implement Product.AssociatedCategories and Category.AssociatedProducts as methods rather than virtual ICollection<T> properties...by querying against the suggested ProductCategoryXrefMap class....I'm hoping it won't have to much of a performance impact.