# Create relation without create a foreing key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the next entities:

- **Publication:** saves every publication.
- **Category:** list of categories.
- **PublicationCategory:** links every publication with their assigned categories.

**Publication.cs**

```
public class Publication
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public Guid ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PublicationCategory> PublicationCategories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I want access to PublicationCategory from this.context.Publication, but if I create the relation with

```
public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

then the foreing key **PublicationId** is created in the table generated by **Category.cs**

I want the relation, but not create a foreing key in **Category**.

Comment: Unless you need additional properties to describe a many-to-many join you don't need to define the PublicationCategories class yourself. Otherwise, you drop the Property for Categories. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819893/entity-framework-6-adding-properties-to-join-tables).

Comment: @Jasen And then how I create PublicationCategories with EF?

Comment: If you are trying to model an existing table see the linked answer above.